# iOS - AVAudioRecorder - recording with ADPCM or IMA

Tags: avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession, adpcm

USing these recording settings, I am able to get the AVAudioRecorder to work:

```
    recordSetting = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
//                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2048.0f],AVSampleRateKey,
//                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
//                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:8],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM],AVFormatIDKey,
//                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
//                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:0], AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
//                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
//                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:256], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                     [NSData data], AVChannelLayoutKey, nil];


recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];


if(!recorder){
    NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                               message: [err localizedDescription]
                              delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    return;
}
```

As soon as I change this:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM],AVFormatIDKey,
```

to this:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4],AVFormatIDKey,
```

I get the following error:

```
recorder: NSOSStatusErrorDomain 1718449215 {
}
```

Which is to say, the audio format is not supported. `kAudioFormatUnsupportedDataFormatError`

What do I need to do to get ADPCM or IMA to work with AVAudioRecorder?

Comment: I'm currently using this library to do the encoding: http://www.microchip.com/ckc/ck763/Code/NetVox.X/Audio/audio_adpcm.c

Comment: pastebin: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8tfR8vdZ

Answer (score 0):

1) Please ensure that you set the session correctly for either Recording (or) Playback (or) Both (i.e. VOIP) as follows:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
```

2) Use the following code, as this works fine for me (I compress to low quality as I have a messaging app):

```
NSDictionary *AudioSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4], AVFormatIDKey
                               , [NSNumber numberWithFloat:11025.00], AVSampleRateKey
                               , [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey
                               , [NSNumber numberWithInt:11025], AVEncoderBitRateKey
                               , [NSNumber numberWithInt:8], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey
                               , [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey
                               , [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey
                               , nil
                               ];
```

Regards
Heider Sati